# Issue in integrating ZKT finger print device into dotnet core api project

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, fingerprint, zkteco

I am using zkemkeeper to integrate ZKT into dotnet core api project. I add simply package reference `<PackageReference Include="ZKemkeeper" Version="1.0.2"/>`

Then create a class named ZkemClient and inherit from IZKEM and implement all of its methods the class and its constructor is. I am not mentioning all methods of IZKEM.

```
    public class ZkemClient  : IZKEM  
    {
        //     Action<object, string> RaiseDeviceEvent;

        // public ZkemClient(Action<object, string> RaiseDeviceEvent)
        // { this.RaiseDeviceEvent = RaiseDeviceEvent; }
        public ZkemClient()
        {
            
        }
        CZKEM objCZKEM = new CZKEM();

    }
```

I am calling it controller like this

```
ZkemClient client = new ZkemClient();
client.Connect_Net("172.16.20.150", 80);
```

It throws exception at CZKEM objCZKEM = new CZKEM(). The is exception "COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00853A19-BD51-419B-9269-2DABE57EB61F} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))." I try a lot of solution but cannot resolve the issue. Try to register zkemkeeper in window 10 64 bit which give me error "The module zkemkeeper.dll failed to load".

Comment: Did you install the Core Driver in the machine?  Does device work with vendors utilities?  Always get devices working with vendor tools first before trying to work with c# code.

Comment: Yes, I had install a driver with ZKT SDK.

Comment: Did you try to register with regsrv32? See :https://blog.csdn.net/qq_24511731/article/details/55049918

Comment: I have re register all the dll and then try to register with regsrv32 but the error still persist.

Comment: What are the project settings?  You probably need X86 or X32.  AnyCPU defaults to 32 bit mode.  The error indicates you are running a 64 bit application.

Comment: How could i change to x86 in vscode. I am trying on this solution as well but donot know to change to x86.

Comment: I am using dotnet core and api template

Comment: In VS the Project Properties.

Comment: Where is project properties in vscode or i will use visual studio

Comment: Project : Properties : Build.  The configuration and Platform at top.